# "What's that noise?"

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've noticed a few questions along the lines of "What could [noise x] mean?" or "How can I fix [noise y]?".  As this is a site dedicated to motor vehicle mechanical issues, I expect this will be a common theme in some questions here.  Should we create a tag or tags for these?

Some example threads are below.  (Some may be better examples than others.):

[My Car Squeals When Braking Even Though I've Had My Front Rotors Machined and Back Rotors Replaced and all new brake pads. What could it be?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/204/my-car-squeals-when-braking-even-though-ive-had-my-front-rotors-machined-and-bac)

[Steering wheel gives a "cluck" sound](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/129/steering-wheel-gives-a-cluck-sound)

[What could cause an engine to make a chirping sound when it's first started up?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-could-cause-an-engine-to-make-a-chirping-sound-when-its-first-started-up)

[How do I silence squeaky springs on a 2006 VW Golf?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/49/how-do-i-silence-squeaky-springs-on-a-2006-vw-golf)

[2008 Jeep Wrangler - Suspension squeaks](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/59/suspension-squeaks)

[Is there a general fix or product I can buy to silence a squeaky belt?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/71/is-there-a-general-fix-or-product-i-can-buy-to-silence-a-squeaky-belt)

[High-pitched squealing coming from engine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/232/high-pitched-squealing-coming-from-engine)

If we do want to create tags for these particular types of questions, should we create one generic [noise](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise) tag, or several different tags for types of noises like [squeal](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/squeal), [clunk](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clunk), [chirp](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chirp), [squeak](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/squeak), etc.?

---

EDIT:  Possible alternative to [noise](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise) which can also be taken as a synonym for spam or other unwanted content, would be [noises](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noises).

Comment: Maybe it's because most people coming to this site already know better, but I'm still amazed that not one of those questions you linked to was about heat shields!

Answer (score 7):

I think I'd just go with [noise](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise) for the moment.